# Can MathJax be made to only convert LaTeX if it's inside a certain tag?

Tags: javascript, latex, mathjax

I have a text editor in which a user can write HTML code. I don't want them to write LaTeX outside of a particular element. It might be something like:

```
<x-latexmath>...</x-latexmath>
```

I want it so if they have LaTeX math outside of that tag, it's just displayed as normal text. How might this be possible?

Comment: `elements`: http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/options/hub.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MathJax doesn't have a way to use user-defined tags to trigger math processing, but you can use MathJax's tex2jax preprocessor's `processClass` and `ignoreClass` parameters to allow you to control which parts of the page to process. See the [text2jax configuration](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/options/tex2jax.html) for details, but the idea would be to use

```
<body class="tex2jax_ignore">
...
<span class="tex2jax_process">...</span>
...
</body>
```

so that the main part of the page isn't processed, and only the span's (or div's if you prefer) containing the mathematics will be processed by MathJax.

Comment: Yes, the math within these elements still needs to have delimiters like `$...$` or `$$...$$`.  The classes described here only say which sections of the page in which the math delimiters will be processed.